Update/Refresh page after updating pictures with power automate
I have a power automate flow that will generate pictures that are saved/overwrite in a sharepoint library. (can be sitepage or another library).
I also have a sharepoint page that show theses pictures in an image web part.
Unfortunately, the pictures are not refreshed, or at least there is a big delay for the page to sync back. I understand it's part of the way sharepoint are built.
I was hopping there was a way to ask sharepoint to refresh that page. Trigger a refresh instead of waiting for the delay trigger.
May be using rest-api, but I couldn't find that information.
Anyone have an idea ?
Thank you

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is currently no direct REST API call in SharePoint to refresh a page.
